# Case-insenstive string comparison strange behavior

Tags: java, c#, .net, unicode

This happens in both C# and Java so I think it's not a bug, just wonder why.

```
var s = "";
var lower = s.ToLower();
var upper = s.ToUpper();

if (!lower.Equals(upper, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    //How can this happen?
}
```

According to [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10401/index.htm), the lower case of "" is "", they should be the equal when comparing with `IgnoreCase` option. Why they are not equal?

Comment: @AccessDenied the test case in the original question is more than adequate and absurd enough

Comment: what's the java code you tried this with?

Comment: How it works under the hood: line 697 GlobalizationNative_CompareStringOrdinalIgnoreCase https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/030a3ea9b8dbeae89c90d34441d4d9a1cf4a7de6/src/corefx/System.Globalization.Native/collation.cpp

Comment: That's why it works the same in Java. It uses the same library http://icu-project.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In defense of the Java API: the [documentation of the method `String.equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) has never claimed that it would work "as expected" on arbitrary Unicode code points. It says:

> Two characters c1 and c2 are considered the same ignoring case if at
>   least one of the following is true:
>
> - The two characters are the same (as compared by the == operator)
> - Applying the method Character.toUpperCase(char) to each character produces the same result
> - Applying the method Character.toLowerCase(char) to each character produces the same result

So, the documentation states quite unambiguously that it applies `Character.toUpperCase` to `char`s, that is, to UTF-16 *code units*, not to Unicode code points.

If you use the method `Character.toUpperCase(int codePoint)` on every code *point*, then the comparison behaves as expected. Here is a short example in Scala (uses the exact same Java API, the higher-order `forall` method is hopefully self-explanatory):

```
val a = ""
val b = ""
(a.codePoints.toArray zip b.codePoints.toArray).forall { 
  case (x, y) => 
  Character.toLowerCase(x) == Character.toLowerCase(y) 
}
```

prints

```
true
```

as expected. Why this is? I think one can safely blame this one on backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You may get more interesting values, when you cast both "" and "" to their numeric values. You get for both the same integer value of 55297 as cast result. StringComparison.Ordinal is based on the numeric values of the characters. Since "Ordinal" means "number based", and both characters (capital and small) have the same ordinal value after cast, any "number based" comparison would provide unexpected results.  OrdinalIgnoreCase is apparently not defined for characters which have the same "ordinal" value for both capital and small version of the character, to avoid unexpected results, and would fail (i.e. result in false) when comparing such characters.